# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wireless not working on Dell with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager, atheros

I can't connect to my wifi on my Ubuntu partition. It says ' No Wifi Adapter is found' in the wifi tab.

I have used rf kill unblock all(There are no soft/hard blocks) and other solutions offered by many users on this website.
Here is my network configuration:

```
       description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 31
   serial: 54:13:79:c2:9f:2b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-53-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:135 memory:d1000000-d11fffff
```

How should I proceed to get my wifi back up?